# Autosys Job Condition based on time and success

Tags: autosys, jil

I have an autosys job_2 that I want to start based on either the success of job_1 OR the time reaches 12:00 PM, where the job will just run regardless of the success of job_1 or not. Job_2 will be active at the same time job_1 runs.

the two conditions to run:

1. Start on success(job_1).
2. Current time reaches 12:00 PM.

How would I specify this in the condition parameter of the jil?

Would it be:
condition: success(job_1) OR (12:00)

Or would I have to create 2 separate jobs with one condition each?

I have not seen any documentation on this yet. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks.